# how to pass command line arguments with protractor conf

Tags: node.js, protractor, cucumberjs

We have protractor-cucumber framework as e2e test. Till now we use the conf file with statically mentioning the environment details inside the conf json. I would like to pass user defined arguments with the protractor_conf file something like below.

```
protractor protractor_conf.js -DbrowserName=chrome -DexecPlatform=(native/sauce)
```

and would like to fetch this argument inside the conf.js and substitute under the capabilities section. I could not get proper details on net, so any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: any help on this please?

Answer (score 3):

You can add Parameters in your **conf.js** file then pass the **arugs** from the command line.

Here is an example.

```
   // The params object will be passed directly to the Protractor instance,
   // and can be accessed from your test as browser.params. It is an arbitrary
   // object and can contain anything you may need in your test.
   // This can be changed via the command line as:
   //   --params.environment.Browser "Firefox"

params: {
  environment: {
   browser: 'Chrome',
   execPlatform: 'sauce',
   password: 'default'
  }
}
```

Now from we can pass the arugs from command line

```
protractor conf.js --parameters.environment.browser= Firefox --parameters.environment.execPlatform=sauce --parameters.environment.password=password123
```

Next, you can also refer these parameters in your spec file.

```
describe('describe some test', function() {
  it('describe some step', function() {
    $('.password').sendKeys(browser.params.login.password);
   });
});
```

There are multiple advantages to having a parameter setup.

- If we know we are going to be using the same values in multiple spec files (i.e login email and password), parameters are great for removing unnecessary repetition.
- Being able to change parameter values at runtime makes it easier to run the same tests with different data.
- Increases security – Having passwords hardcoded in your spec files is not a great approach. Parameters give you the ability to keep them out and instead provide them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `process` api to parse the arguments in cmd line.

```
// protractor conf.js

var readParamsFromCli = function() {

    var paramsPair = process.argv.slice(3).filter(function(it){
        return it.startsWith('-D');
    });

    var params = {};

    paramsPair.forEach(function(pair){
        var parts = pair.split('=');
        var name = parts[0].trim().replace('-D', '');
        var value = parts[1] && parts[1].trim() || true;
        params[name] = value;
    });


    return params;
};

var params = readParamsFromCli();

var capbilities = {
    browserName: params.browserName || 'chrome',
    platform: params.execPlatform
};

exports.config = {
    ...
    capbilities: capbilities

};
```

Then you can run case as following:

```
protractor protractor_conf.js -DbrowserName=chrome -DexecPlatform=native
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the configuration up into multiple config files. For example *protractor-chrome.conf.js*:

```
const baseConf = require('./protractor.conf').config;

exports.config = Object.assign({
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}, baseConf);
```

Comment: Thank you. i got this idea. With this approach i have a question. When doing `Object.assign()` we assign a new property like capabilities mentioned above. But how to replace a value of an existing key. For example, i have `cucumberOpts: { tags:['@regression'] }` in the main config as baseline template. While executing the regression suite i get the tags to be executed from the command-line and get it thro' yargs in a variable. With this `Object.assign()` how can i replace the existing tag array value to be the one needed?

Comment: Then you should not use my solution, but pass command line parameters directly into _protractor_: `protractor conf.js --cucumberOpts.tags @regression`

Answer (score 0):

This will be similar to 2nd example but uses the config file directly.

```
const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
exports.config = {
  //your config stuff
  baseUrl: args.Url ? args.URL : <your default>,
  capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   chromeOptions: {
     args: [args.Options]
    },
   }
}
```

Then in your package.json script like this:

```
"e2e": "protractor protractor.conf.js --Url=http://test.com" --Options=--headless
```