# How to pass arguments by command line for multicapabilities on protractor?

Tags: protractor

I need to pass headless arguments by command line.

In the begining I was working just with Chrome and I was using the following code to pass these arguments:

```
./node_modules/.bin/protractor "conf.js" --capabilities.chromeOptions.args=headless --capabilities.chromeOptions.args=disable-gpu --capabilities.chromeOptions.args=window-size=1248,1024
```

This is working properly, the problem is when I added firefox capabilities.

The qwestion: How can I pass this "headless" argument by command line with multiCapabilities?

I tried with:

```
./node_modules/.bin/protractor "conf.js" --multiCapabilities.1.chromeOptions.args=headless --multiCapabilities.1.chromeOptions.args=disable-gpu --multiCapabilities.1.chromeOptions.args=window-size=1248,1024 --multiCapabilities.0.moz:firefoxOptions=headless
```

But didn't work.

My config file:

```
exports.config = {
onPrepare: async function () {
    console.log("Let's Start")
    },
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
getPageTimeout: 100000,
allScriptsTimeout: 100000,
restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
maxSessions: 2,
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'firefox',
    parallelCapability: false,
    marionette: true,
    "moz:firefoxOptions":{
        //args: [ "--headless" ],
        prefs:{
            'pdfjs.disabled': true
        }
    },
    'safebrowsing': {
        'enabled': true,
    }
}
,{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    parallelCapability: false,
    'chromeOptions': {
        prefs: {
            download: {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/download/'
            },
            'safebrowsing': {
                'enabled': true,
            }
        }
    },
  },
],
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
specs: [
    'features/happyPath.feature'
],
cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
        'features/step_definitions/**/*.js',
        'lib/hooks.js'],
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
}
```

};

Comment: Should be same solution in my answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822861/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-with-protractor-conf/52827192#52827192

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the browser name

```
--multiCapabilities.0.browserName chrome
--multiCapabilities.1.browserName firefox
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to add just the args for chrome (or firefox), no the browser name.

Comment: i think the --multiCapabilities overwrites the whole array, so you have to specify all settings.